# Make div appear next to other

Tags: html, css

I have started a huge revision on my css knowledge.
I am trying to do the following:
I want to create a wrapper div that contains to divs with some text and some content.I want each div with class `item-2` inside that div to have a width:50%
and appear next to another `item-2`.
Here is a snippet of my code:

```css
body{
  background:rgba(10,10,10,.8);
}
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;  
}
.item-2{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    border:2px solid blue;
 }
.demo{
  margin:auto;
  height:5em;
  width:5em;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='item-2'>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class='demo'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='item-2'>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class='demo'>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

As you can see it's div appears below its previous div.However I want them to be next to each other.How can I achieve this? I would like an explanation to your solution sa as to improve my knowledge

Comment: Give `float: left; box-sizing: border-box;` to `.item-2`

Comment: thanks that did the trick but can you explain why?

Comment: `item-2` width = 50%(parent) + 4px(left and right border) so the two div can't place next to each others. by `box-sizing`, width = 50% - 4px

Comment: u can achieve that by `display:inline-block` and `box-sizing` too but u have  to [remove extra space which is occurred by](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why is this happening?

Using `inline-block` in this way is perfectly valid and will work but you have two issues that are causing the elements to occupy separate lines:

1. `inline-block` items honour the white-space between elements so there is an extra space between the two `.item-2` `div`s
2. The `width` of `.item-2` is not `50%` but `50%` + `2px` left border + `2px` right border

## How to fix

1. There are multiple ways of getting round the white-space issue including setting `font-size: 0;`, however, as the `height` and `width`  of `.demo` use `em`s you are probably best removing the white-space from between the elements in the HTML instead
2. To ensure `.item-2` actually has a `width` of `50%` you can add `box-sizing: border-box;` which will make the `width` and `height` include the `padding` and `border`

```css
body {
  background: rgba(10, 10, 10, .8);
}

.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.item-2 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.demo {
  background: yellow;
  height: 5em;
  margin: auto;
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='item-2'>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class='demo'>
    </div>
  </div><!--You can remove the white-space by adding a comment between the elements
  --><div class='item-2'>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class='demo'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.wrapper display: flex;
.item-2 flex: 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Flex can keep them in one row.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
 }
```

And remove `display: inline block` for items. If you want in small devices they are under each other add this to `.wrapper`

```
  flex-wrap: wrap;
```

And we need a `min-width` for items. `.items: min-width: 250px;`. If your device has enough space (500px) they will remain in one line, else the second item goes to next line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```css
body{
  background:rgba(10,10,10,.8);
}
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;  
}
.item-2{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    border:2px solid blue;
 }
.demo{
  margin:auto;
  height:5em;
  width:5em;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='item-2'>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class='demo'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='item-2'>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class='demo'>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, If I've repeated answer but actually I was formatting my answer and at same time others had given solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

aside `float` and `flex`, there's also:

- `display:table;`

```css
body{
  background:rgba(10,10,10,.8);
}
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  margin:auto; 
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;/* to even cells and keep within width set */
}
.item-2{
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    border:2px solid blue;
 }
.demo{
  margin:auto;
  height:5em;
  width:5em;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='item-2'>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class='demo'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='item-2'>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class='demo'>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

- `display:grid;`

```css
body{
  background:rgba(10,10,10,.8);
}
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  margin:auto; 
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:50% 50%;
}
.item-2{
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid blue;
 }
.demo{
  margin:auto;
  height:5em;
  width:5em;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='item-2'>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class='demo'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='item-2'>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div class='demo'>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```